# How technique can i use in making my server accept request from a game i built in unity?

Tags: api, unity-game-engine

I am creating a unity game where users can post their high scores after a successful match, my problem is that some users can post directly to the api, without playing a match. How do i curb such an issue. I have read some articles about using native mobile encryption to help. but i do not know how this can be applied to Unity since it is a layer above native.  what techniques can i use ?

Comment: Encryption doesn't solve this problem, it just makes it harder. You want to solve the problem, don't accept the client's word as truth. Remember: the client is a lying, cheating bastard that can't be trusted.

Comment: Can't remember it's name but there is something you can use.  Merge your parameters to one string like "username + score + level"   and encrypt them. Send them with your other parameters. Then on server side, do the same thing on parameters "username + score + level" you have your server created hash and client hash. If they are same, your request is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption will only solve a part of the problem, when users send fake requests to your API. But if I were you, I would perform server-side validation based on the parameters sent by the client.

How: Send one request to the server when a match starts, along with necessary details such as the user name. When the match is finished, send another request to the server, check the score against some heuristics based on how long the match took, and whether the score makes sense given the user's specific setup (levels and equipment, etc.) if you keep that information on the server.

Why: There's no reliable way to control what the user does on his client: he can change the values in memory, send forged requests, and so on. If the user meddles with the memory to give himself "100x damage dealt", your client may not know, and will dutifully record the (now tampered) score and send it to the web API. Encryption will not help you here since the request is just like the real thing except it contained a fake score to start with.